# After shading io.netty tcnative stops working

Tags: java, netty, google-cloud-pubsub

Because of a conflict in dependencies I want to shade io.netty. After shading, the loading of the native ssl libraries (netty-tcnative-boringssl-static) stops working.

**Main pom**

My main pom has this dependency:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pubsub-library<artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

**Library that does the shading**

The pubsub-library pom is like this:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.24.0-beta</version>
<dependency>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <relocations>
                  <relocation>
                      <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                          <shadedPattern>com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty</shadedPattern>
                  </relocation>
              </relocations>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

the pubsub has these 3 dependencies: `io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.14.Final`, `io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.14.Final` and `io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.3.Final`

**Error**

The problem arises when `io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader` tries to load the native library. It gives me errors such as:

```
17:44:48.230 [main] DEBUG com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/ll/wy1vgf8945l_87mpfc9ylb94fglr7d/T (java.io.tmpdir)
17:44:48.230 [main] DEBUG com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /var/folders/ll/wy1vgf8945l_87mpfc9ylb94fglr7d/T (io.netty.tmpdir)
17:44:48.241 [main] DEBUG com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'com.example.myapp-shaded-netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no com.example.myapp-shaded-netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:303)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:291)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:172)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:423)
    at com.example.myapp.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:91)
    at com.example.myapp.job.audit.GoogleCloudCompatChecker.check(GoogleCloudCompatChecker.java:30)
    at com.example.myapp.job.audit.AuditJobMain.main(AuditJobMain.java:8)
```

I have looked inside the jar generated by the main pom. And no native library matches that name. This is inside the META-INF/native directory:

```
libnetty-tcnative-linux-x86_64.so
libnetty-tcnative-osx-x86_64.jnilib
libnetty-transport-native-epoll.so
linux32
linux64
netty-tcnative-windows-x86_64.dll
osx
windows32
windows64
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I shade io.netty without breaking tcnative.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [NativeLibraryLoader source](https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/util/internal/NativeLibraryLoader.html).

This might not be the same version you're using but it indicates that it uses few heuristics to find the native libraries and most propably these heuristics fail on shade but might be easy to fix

Studying code carefully and maybe overriding/debugging/logging NativeLibraryLoader.

Are you forced to use two versions of some dependency libraries so that you cannot just use maven exclusions ?